# Hbase start failed because of The hostname of regionserver cannot be set to localhost

Tags: hbase

I have three nodes to start Hbase cluster, but it failed to start HMenter and  Regionservers, the exception as follows:

```
FATAL [main] regionserver.RSRpcServices: The hostname of regionserver cannot be set to localhost in a fully-distributed setup because it won't be reachable. See "Getting Started" for more information.
2015-04-05 09:11:58,160 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:1982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:1996)
#127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The hostname of regionserver cannot be set to localhost in a fully-distributed setup because it won't be reachable.
```

It was saying the regionservers's host name is Localhost. But it's not, my two regionservers's hostnames are dev1.test.local and dev2.test.local respectively.
Also I designated the IPs in the configuration file RegionServers. 
I'm curious why the HMaster think the RegionServer's hostname is localhost?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

In hbase 1.0, You can not add master as region server.

Comment: Thank you so much OP. I guess I didn't add master as region server, I have three nodes: 192.168.100.5,192.168.100.6,192.168.100.7. 100.5 is the master, 100.6 and 100.7 are slaves.
In the file RegionServers I input the following two IPs: 192.168.100.6,192.168.100.7. And copied the file RegionServers to each node. Did I do anything wrong please.

Comment: can you add your hbase-site.xml and region servers list?

Comment: Thank you so much OP, the following is my hbase-site.xml:
<property>
<name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/data/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://192.168.100.6:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>192.168.100.6</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.master</name>
<value>192.168.100.7:60000</value>
</property>
My Region server are: 192.168.100.6 192.168.100.8

Comment: <name>hbase.master</name>
 <value>192.168.100.7:60000</value> change port number to 60010

Comment: And define ZK port number 2222

Comment: Thanks OP, finally I fixed the problem, it's because the hostname issue.
First: We need to use hostname to indicate regionServer rather IP
Second: We need to add the hostname and IP pair on /etc/hosts, for example:
local1.domain1.d1  192.168.100.6
local2.domain1.d1  192.168.100.7